# Не работает WiFi адаптер на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, lubuntu

Решил перейти с винды 7 на Ubuntu (lubuntu если точнее) и столкнулся с проблемой. Не работает адаптер RT2870 (MT7601U) и никак не хочет работать. Пробывал различные драйвера с сайтов, но в большинстве происходит ошибка компиляции или же вообще ничего не происходит. Может кто-то сталкивался с таким?
Без Wifi трудно(

Comment: ставил себе WIFI-адаптер в PCI Express слот ещё лет 5 назад - проблем вообще не было...по-моему ставить даже ничего не пришлось на убунту...завелась сразу...С полгода назад  помучался с установкой TL-WN725N на Убунту...но к сожалению как именно заставил его работать не помню...помню что сам дурак был и тупо не заметил что он начал работать...плюс с настройкой сети напортачил

Comment: Он виден в lsusb, но в iwconfig его вообще нет. Странно это все

Comment: ну так мало драйвер установить, нужно еще настроить сеть

Comment: посмотрите что пишет по этому поводу `dmesg`

Comment: Пишет, что подключено, но дальше пустота. Бывало, что писало неизвестный символ, но это было после того, как я пытался установить другой драйвер